# 'require is not defined' in Meteor.js when including NPM package

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, meteorite

I'm trying to use a npm package from Meteor.js *(Release 0.6.6.3)* using `Meteor.require`. However it throws an error saying that `require` is not defined. Why is this and how can we solve it?

```
mrt add npm
npm install github
```

**packages.json**

```
{
    "github": "0.1.8"
}
```

**github.js**

```
var GITHUB = Meteor.require('github');
```

**Error**

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

---

The npm package has lines such as

```
var https = require('https')
var url = require('url')
var crypto = require('crypto')
```

Must the package's code be manually edited to use `Npm.require`? Editing them manually got rid of the errors.

However theres a line:

```
module.exports = SOMETHING
```

How should we call `module` from within meteor?

Comment: Is `Meteor.require()` a typo?  That is what is in your code though your question text refers to the correct `Npm.require()`

Comment: It was a typo, corrected it!

Comment: `Npm.require()` is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks that works! What should I edit `module.exports` to? `Npm.module.exports` does not work...

Answer (score 10):

`Meteor.require` is a function added by the [meteor npm smart package](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm), which actually doesn't do much for using npm other than wrapping some asynchronous callbacks. It's a few months old, so you might want to try using Meteor's `Npm.require` directly in case something broke.

The monkey-patching of the `Meteor` global by this package is misleading.

Answer (score 4):

Making comments above an answer.

Is Meteor.require() a typo? That is what is in your code though your question text refers to the correct Npm.require().

I think module.exports is there for non-meteor use of the same file.  Within meteor variables for export should be

1. declared as globals inside the package
2. exported with api.export() within the package.js file.

The documentation on this is a bit rough but look at [namespacing](http://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing) and [writing packages](http://docs.meteor.com/#writingpackages).  Also looking into the various [meteor packages](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/799dd35319177cd3c3502e366f4b955925ea59bd/packages) on github is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use Npm.require() in meteor.

Like this:

```
var fs = Npm.require("fs");
```

For that you need to have a Meteor package: `meteorhacks:npm` , `npm-container`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the `meteor-npm` package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-npm