# Meteor/React : ReferenceError: require is not defined / Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, npm, require

I have to use Meteor with React for a school project.
I build a website in which I'd like to add a carousel.

To do so, I tried to use : https://github.com/vazco/meteor-universe-react-carousel/

With the example script :

```
var React = require('react');
var Slider = require('react-slick');

var SimpleSlider = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    return (
      <Slider {...settings}>
        <div><h3>1</h3></div>
        <div><h3>2</h3></div>
        <div><h3>3</h3></div>
        <div><h3>4</h3></div>
        <div><h3>5</h3></div>
        <div><h3>6</h3></div>
      </Slider>
    );
  }
});
```

Using this code, I get : ReferenceError: require is not defined (l1)

After some research, I saw several solutions that didn't work for me, like using Meteor.require or Npm.require.

I followed links like ['require is not defined' in Meteor.js when including NPM package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040061/require-is-not-defined-in-meteor-js-when-including-npm-package)
or [Meteor cannot find module "module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565679/meteor-cannot-find-module-module)

Now I'm a bit lost in all this, how can I use a package imported with meteor add package ? Is meteorite deprecated, do I need to use npm ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`how can I use a package imported with meteor add package`

Meteor packages are exported to the global namespace and are made available to the client and/or the server as declared in the package's `package.js` file. Module support is coming in Meteor 1.3. That example in the documentation is not possible without adding another package that supports the require syntax, such as `meteorhacks:npm` and/or `cosmos:browserify`.